# How to set access timeout for Web APP in WSO2?

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, wso2

Does anyone know how to configure the request timeout to a Web App served by WSO2 app server?
I couldn't find yet how to set this timeout, or at least find out what's default. WSO2 is a great app server, but lacks good documentation.

I'm making specific calls to web services contained in a Java Web App (exported as .war), that is hosted by WSO2 app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question you are hosting a web app in WSO2 AS.

You can specify the timeout of a session in the deployment descriptor of your web application (web.xml):

```
<web-app>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  ...
</web-app>
```

The number within the session-timout element must be expressed in minutes.

Thanks...